# Getting the input that autocomplete is called on in select event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jquery ui autocomplete acting upon a text input. When the "select" event fires, I need to use the text input to locate a nearby hidden input and fill it.

The problem is that the event's target differs between when you press enter and when you click on the autocomplete. When pressing enter, the event's target is the input. However, when you click the event's target is the link in the autocomplete. As the link in the autocomplete is not DOM-wise related to the input, I can't find it to fill my hidden input.

What is the correct way to find the original input that the autocomplete was called upon, within the select event?